# Scanner nosuchelement exception

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I saw people were closing the scanner and getting this. but in my case the used code is:

```
BlobDomain blobDomain = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    blobDomain = new BlobDomain();
    out = blobDomain.getBinaryOutputStream();
    if (status != null){
        fullText = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (out != null)
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)
```

Comment: That's a lot of exception handling. Can you use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)?

Comment: Why are you using `.useDelimiter("\\A")`? Also what is `in`?

Comment: to read entire text as a single stirng, in is inputstream

Comment: "*`in` is inputstream*" but what kind of data does it stream? Is it `System.in`? Is it some kind of `FileInputStream`?

Comment: Please provide us with the type of stream you are using, as well as why you're using "\\A" as a delimiter to read an entire text - really, what is at the end of this text that could possibly justify not using the default delimiter?